# How to implement the NDSolve divide by zero event?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a situation when using NDSolve to numerically evaluate the coupled equation system.  For this discussion I provide a toycode that describes the same problem.

```
ClearAll;
solution=NDSolve[{x''[t]+2*x'[t]+x[t]/(x[t]^2+y[t]^2)==0,y''[t]+2*y'[t]+y[t]/(x[t]^2+y[t]^2)==0,x[0]==5,y[0]==0,x'[0]==0,y'[0]==0},{x,y},{t,0,20}];  
Plot[x[t]/.solution,{t,0,20}] 
solution1=NDSolve[{x''[t]+2*x'[t]+x[t]/(x[t]^2+y[t]^2)==0,y''[t]+2*y'[t]+y[t]/(x[t]^2+y[t]^2)==0,x[0]==0,y[0]==0,x'[0]==1,y'[0]==0},{x,y},{t,0,20}];  
Plot[x[t]/.solution1,{t,0,20}]
```

Th problem in this code in solution1 is that my initial conditions for x and y are set to zero which leads to division by zero or more precisely 0/0.  Adding epsilon with a very high decimal is not correct approach.  Furthermore I do not want to modify equation to get rid of denominator term because my original equation is far too complicated.  As far as I can see, the best solution is to add event for ndsolve and tell it to multiply the troublesome term (with the denominator) by zero because denominators are always positive.  How to implement that event step in ndsolve command?  Something like event[divide by zero, err=0 else err=1] then the equations can be easily modified so that they become

```
 x''[t]+2*x'[t]+err*x[t]/(x[t]^2+y[t]^2)==0,y''[t]+2*y'[t]+err*y[t]/(x[t]^2+y[t]^2)==0
```

Also in first solution I cannot increase t above 26 because of
step size is effectively zero,singularity or stiff system suspected.  Probably for the same reason as above.

**My attempted solution to the above problem:**

```
attempt1=NDSolve[{x''[t]+2*x'[t]+x[t]/(x[t]^2+y[t]^2)==0,
 y''[t]+2*y'[t]+y[t]/(x[t]^2+y[t]^2)==0,
 x[0]==0,y[0]==0,x'[0]==1,y'[0]==0,
 WhenEvent[x[t]==0 && y[t]==0,"RemoveEvent"]},{x,y},{t,0,20}];  
 Plot[Evaluate[x[t]/.attempt1],{t,0,20}]
```

I also tried with RestartIntegration and CrossDiscontinuity.

Comment: 1. You're using `ClearAll` in wrong way, please don't imagine its usage, check the document of `ClearAll` carefully by pressing **F1**. 2. Are you sure the problem itself is correct? Can you add some background info?

Comment: Your problem is not 0/0 what could have a limiting value, but 0/0^2 what diverges. Therefore, I think the equation is wrong.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no solution to the problem as posed.